# Visual Studio 2015 cannot connect to SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm just starting to learn C# and Entity Framework 6 ... and it's already far worse than I expected.

I have created a simple new project, and added EF6, while creating to database with `Update-Database`, I get:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I haven't changed any config or anything, just created some classed and wanted to generate the database, here is the default connection factory:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="MSSQLLocalDB" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

I even checked if the instance is running by running this command:

```
sqllocaldb info
```

which resulted in:

```
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectsV13
```

and same for this:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe start
LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started.
```

I have even tried to disable the firewall ... but nothing.

EDIT:
App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="MSSQLLocalDB" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after i saw your project you just need change the app.config connectionStrings

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="masterEntities"
     connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=master;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not work, and in the tutorial im following, he did not add anything.

Comment: its on `pluralsight` called `Getting Started with Entity Framework 6`

Comment: I found a similar official tutorial . i guess you are learning EF code first 
in this article you can see it's need to setting connectionStrings . 
what's your connectionStrings value ?
you can refer : https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I havent changed anything is the App.config (like the author of the tutorial did), i have updated my question with the full app.config (I have tried with the connectionString you suggested but same results)

Comment: i have edit my answer . and it's test by winform application.
i think you lose a connection config on dbContext

Comment: thank you for your effort, i tried your new solution but didnt work either, but with a desperate try, i have created a new solution with only one project with EF6, and with no DbSet, it worked ... i have no idea whats wrong in the previous project.

Comment: if you want , please send your previous project to me .  
a926a926@gmail.com 
i believe it can connect to  localdb  :D

Comment: i resolved a issued .  you need change your app.config  please see my updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to find the solution (or workaround?), you kept referring to the App.Config, so i added the same App.Config to the "Classes" Project (which have EF as a reference too), and it worked, is that normal?

Comment: i send a mail of my resolved result :)  if you're use EF makesure you have right connection string to connect your database ~